# Simple SQL query with MAX()

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I need some help with this task:

Database schema:

```
Comic(no primary key NOT NULL, title, pages, publisher)
PoweredPerson(alias primary key NOT NULL, firstname NOT NULL, lastname, evilness_level)
SuperHero(alias primary key→PoweredPerson NOT NULL,cape)
SuperVillain(alias primary key→PoweredPerson NOT NULL)
FightIn(comic primary key→ Comic NOT NULL,hero primary key→ SuperHero NOT NULL,villain primary key→ SuperVillain NOT NULL)
```

Now I shall declare a SQL query which gives the first and last names of those powered person(s) that fought the most enemies in just one comic.

My solution is this:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname
FROM fightIn f 
JOIN poweredperson p
ON f.hero = p.alias OR f.villain= p.alias
GROUP BY comic,alias
HAVING COUNT(alias)=(SELECT COUNT(alias)
                     FROM fightIn f 
                     JOIN poweredperson p
                     ON f.hero = p.alias OR f.villain = p.alias
                     GROUP BY comic,alias
                     ORDER BY COUNT(hero) DESC
                     LIMIT 1)
```

I want to know if my solution is correct and in case it is, whether there is a much smarter and shorter way to solve this.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "p.alias" is the same as "f.hero", why join to get the count.  Also, since you are returning a limit of 1, why not include the alias with the count so you already have that.  Do it all in one AND be done. Also, as a newbie to SQL, get in the habit of ALWAYS using "table.column" or "tableAlias.column" to prevent ambiguities in where columns come from more complex queries in the future.

```
SELECT
      p.firstname,
      p.lastname,
      MostFights.hero,
      MostFights.Comic,
      MostFights.FightsInComic
   from
      ( SELECT
              f.Comic,
              f.hero,
              COUNT(*) as FightsInComic
           from 
              fightIn f
                 left join SuperVillain sv
                    on f.hero = sv.alias
           where
              sv.alias IS NULL
           group by
              f.Comic,
              f.hero
           order by
              COUNT(*) desc
           limit 1 ) MostFights
      JOIN PoweredPerson p
         ON MostFights.hero = p.alias
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. But i see a problem in your solution. It is also possible, that the poweredperson with the most fights in one comic is a supervillain. I don´t know how to get this into the Query without joining fightIn with poweredPerson.